# Cleanup HTML of a wordpress woocommerce product description?

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, code-cleanup

Is there a tool which it can automatically cleanup unnecessary html codes, add missing html code pairs, remove wrong html code?

Something like this online tool

```
https://html-cleaner.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.

```
function stripe_woocommerce_short_description($the_excerpt) {

    //wp_strip_all_tags will strip all HTML tags including script and style.
    //return wp_strip_all_tags($the_excerpt);

    //pass second parameter true if you want to remove break tag <br/> also.
    //return wp_strip_all_tags( $the_excerpt, true );

   //For Keep specific tags
   return strip_tags($the_excerpt,"<img><table><p>");

}
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', 'stripe_woocommerce_short_description',10, 1);
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep img, table, p tags?

Comment: @stackmike In that case you can use strip_tags($the_excerpt,"<img><table><p>");

Comment: Thanks, If I want to strip product description as well, how shall I add the code?
And do I put the code in functions.php under child theme?